# ¿Cómo puedo especificar una cardinalidad 2 a N en un DTD para un documento XML?

Tags: xml, estructuras-de-datos, xml-schema

Resulta que tengo un ejercicio de clase que consiste en definir el siguiente XML con un DTD y uno de los requerimientos es que le aplique a la etiqueta book una cardinalidad 2 a N. Que yo sepa y por lo que he encontrado en internet, lo más cercano que se puede es poner a book el simbolo "+" que significa que como mínimo debe haber un elemento *book* y máximo muchos, pero cuando le puse eso en el ejercicio me lo da por malo y no da ningún tipo de correción más que eso, ni tampoco responde. Es enseñanza a distancia pública y los profesores pasan totalmente.
Entonces dado el siguiente XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<bookstore>
  <book category="COOKING">
    <title>Everyday Italian</title>
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>49.99</price>
  </book>
  
  <book category="WEB" soldout="true">
    <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
    <author>James McGovern</author>
    <year>2001</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
  </book>      
       
  <sale ident="V.00001">
    <refbook>Learning XML</refbook>
    <date>2019-11-30</date>
  </sale>     

</bookstore>
```

Lo que tengo de DTD en referencia a mi problema sería algo como:

```xml
<!ELEMENT bookstore (book+, sale*)>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conseguí tras muchos tutoriales y búsquedas resolverlo:

```
<!ELEMENT bookstore (book+,book+,sale*)>
```

Con esto, estamos diciendo que por cada elemento *bookstore* tiene que aparecer como mínimo 2 *book* y opcionalmente uno o más *sale*.

Era muy simple la respuesta pero como en los apuntes del instituto no hay ningún ejemplo ni explicación sobre cardinales N a N o como en este caso 2 a N, ni conseguía encontrar nada en relación a esto en internet, no caí en que se hacía de esta manera.